# "uppercaseString" and "lowercaseString" on UITextField crash in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a small application which has 1 `ViewController` with: 2 Outlets (one `UITextField` and one `UILabel`) and 1 Action that is triggered when a button is pressed. The code looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func changeText() {
    label.text = textField.text.lowercaseString
    }
}
```

My questions is why every time I run the app and press the button, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

EDIT 1: It seems that Xcode is the problem. I crashes only on Xcode 6.3 beta, on 6.1.1 it works fine. Here is the project [LINK](https://github.com/alinmuntean/uppercaseSwift)

EDIT 2: Problem SOLVED, Xcode version was the problem, thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Did you get any crash log?

Comment: Are the `IBOutlet` properly linked to Storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, the Outlets are set correctly. In Obj-C works fine, in Swift it crashes. I added the projects here: [link](https://github.com/alinmuntean/uppercaseSwift)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qstsbv67c9jd6ru/uppercaseSwift-master.zip?dl=0

Comment: The problem is with Xcode version, it works fine on 6.1.1 but crashes on 6.3 beta 1.

Comment: Can you upload your log? You must make sure that ViewController's func viewDidLoad is loaded before func changeText.

Comment: There was no problem with my project, it was only the Xcode version.

Comment: @ALN The crash was a bug. Your project doesn't crash with beta 2 but like I said there is no need for a button. You should connect changedText IBAction to your text field using editing changed option

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus Yes, you're right, it's a better solution to do what you suggested, but I saw that it crashed when I was accessing "uppercaseString" / "lowercaseString" in a more complex project, and that's why I created a very simple and quick project. Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with beta 1 and it has being fixed. You are using a button to update the label field but there is no need to use a button for that. You can choose to connect your IBAction to your text Field's Sent Events **Editing Changed** to make it change with a real time as you type preview.

> Swift Compiler • @objc enums no longer cause the compiler to crash
>   when used from another file. (19775284) • Fixed a use after free crash
>   in lowercaseString and uppercaseString. (19801253)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func changeText(sender: AnyObject) {
        label.text = textField.text.lowercaseString
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

[sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcua8vdf53kwema/uppercaseString.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is with Xcode 6.3 beta 1. It works fine on 6.1.1.

Comment: this is a known issue with beta 1 and it has being fixed

Comment: just download the latest build beta 2 released by apple two days ago

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_2/Xcode_6.3_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf